# Word Online (Business) Connector - Populate a Microsoft Word template - how to get values for queries key; drive and file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When a Locic app (in Populate a Microsoft Word template) is adding a Document Library and a File at design time the values are transformed in the code behind view to this below

```
"queries": {

   "drive": "b!pQtOjN9hhkuS3cqytiRbkgLNffrN86lAv6qypCvoFZHH47f9pgvOQbSdIQgHA6Er",
   "file": "01COWZ3YIURGJHT27EDVCJJBJNMGO3QJZ4",
   "source": "https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXX/"
}
```

Hov Can I get those values at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide my code view as an example:
[image]

In my code view, if I want to get the value of "dirve", "file" and "source", I can use the expression below:

**drive:**

```
actions('Populate_a_Microsoft_Word_template').inputs.queries.drive
```

**file:**

```
actions('Populate_a_Microsoft_Word_template').inputs.queries.file
```

**source:**

```
actions('Populate_a_Microsoft_Word_template').inputs.queries.source
```

Set the expression in your next action(such as "Initialize variable" action)
[image]

Then you can get those values and use them.